# moodle external login

Tags: authentication, moodle

I have writing some changes at index.php and index_form.php to login in my mambo server. I recive from mambo the username and md5 password, etc.., then I test if this user is in moodle database, if not create, then login, else login.

The question is that I can't login a user created from this script in moodle, I also tried to log it mannualy in the default login screen, but the password is always wrong.

The insertion script is inserting the password this way: hash_internal_user_password($_SESSION['PHP_AUTH_PW'])

Then I'm trying to login it this way:
location="https://server/moodle/login/index.php?username='. $_SESSION['PHP_AUTH_USER'] .'&password='. $_SESSION['PHP_AUTH_PW']

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's pretty simple

create your login page something like this

```
in your "config.php"
```

$CFG->alternateloginurl = ' your url ';

Answer (score 0):

You can even do it from interface without modifying config file

Just go through following path in your moodle.

```
Home ► Site administration ► Plugins ► Authentication ► Manage authentication
```

You will find.

> Alternate login URL

Put your external login url in this field and save the changes.